# Trying to plot a vector vs another vector in Matlab using piecewise conditionals

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do a piecewise plot of frequencies (f) vs. skin depth (y) by creating the f vector, then creating an empty y vector of the same size and filling it as it meets certain criteria. For some reason, the code is getting stuck in filling the y vector with zeros in the command window. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
e = 80*8.854e-12;
mu = 12.566e-7;
sigma = 4;

f = 1000:100:10000000000;
y = zeros(1, 99999991);

for i=1:length(f)
if (sigma/(2*pi*f(i)*e) < 0.01) 
    y(i) = 1/((sigma/2)*sqrt(mu/e))
elseif ((sigma/(2*pi*f(i)*e) >= 0.01) && (sigma/(2*pi*f(i)*e) <= 100))
    y(i) = 1/(2*pi*f(i)*sqrt((mu*e/2)*(sqrt(1+(sigma./(2*pi*f(i)*e)*sigma./(2*pi*f(i)*e))) - 1)))
elseif (sigma/(2*pi*f(i)*e) > 100)
    y(i) = 1/(sqrt(pi*(2*pi*f(i)/(2*pi))*mu*sigma));
end
end

plot(log(f), log(y));
```

Comment: How much available memory do you have?

Comment: You do a lot of duplicate work there too. Try to pre-compute some of those values, and removing the unnecessary comparisons (`else` already guarantees some properties, no need to check for that again).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and it works fine. It might take a while because of the large arrays, so you just have to be patient.

I would initialize y as `y = zeros(size(f))`, as it is more convenient in case you ever change f. Also, I suggest using `loglog(f, y)` for the plot instead.